# LINQ with Option Strict Error in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm facing a trick issue with LINQ.  I generate the above code:

... 'Returning an Object

```
Dim lReturn = (From tb_hb In lObjLNQContext.tb_hbs _
    Where tb_hb.id_process = codigoProcessamento _
    Order By tb_hb.dth_hb Ascending _
    Select tb_hb.id_process, tb_hb.dth_hb).AsEnumerable

Return lReturn
```

When I check the lReturn DataType is Linq.DataQuery.

I used the code above to access the data:

```
For Each row In lResult
  Console.WriteLine(row.dth_hb)
```

Everything is running well if I turn off Option Explicit.  When I turn it on, compiler is showing me a meessage: Expression is of type 'Object', which is not a collection type.  Referencing to lResult variable.

I realy don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1089059/479512), I think it will help

Answer (score 2):

Your LINQ expression uses anonymous types, which are only available in one method.

Define a class to hold the two values id_process, dth_hb and change your select to create instances of the class. Then you can declare the function as returning List Of the new class

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633908/linq-returning-list-of-anonymous-types)

Comment: Another example [here in this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767831/convert-a-list-linq-expression-to-defined-list-class)