# Convert a list linq expression to Defined list Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, lambda

y have this class

```vb
Private Class MyClass
    Public Property propertyOne() as String
    Public Property propertyTwo() as String
    Public Property propertyN() as Integer
End Class
```

Now i want fill a list of MyClass from lambda or linq expression, some like this....

```vb
    Dim myClassList as new List(Of MyClass)
    myClassList = (From lOtherList1 in MyOtherList1.GetAll()
                   join lOtherList2 in MyOterhList2.GetAll() on lOtherList1.Id Equals lOtherList2.Id
                   Select myClassList.Add(new MyClass With { .propertyOne = lOtherList1.Field1, 
                  .propertyTwo = lOtherList1.Field2,
                  .propertyN = lOtherList2.Field1 })).Tolist()
```

but i get this error "Expression does not produce a value", how i make this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myClassList.Add` is wrong part in your query, edit it as follow:

```
Dim myClassList as new List(Of MyClass)
myClassList = (From lOtherList1 in MyOtherList1.GetAll()
               join lOtherList2 in MyOterhList2.GetAll() 
               on lOtherList1.Id Equals lOtherList2.Id
               Select new MyClass With 
               { 
               .propertyOne = lOtherList1.Field1, 
               .propertyTwo = lOtherList1.Field2,
               .propertyN = lOtherList2.Field1 
               })).Tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do the following:

```
myClassList = (From lOtherList1 in MyOtherList1.GetAll()
               Join lOtherList2 in MyOtherList2.GetAll()
               On lOtherList1.Id Equals lOtherList2.Id
               Select new MyClass With
               {
                   .propertyOne = lOtherList1.Field1,
                   .propertyTwo = lOtherList1.Field2,
                   .propertyN = lOtherList2.Field1
               }).ToList()
```

You almost had the correct code. You just need to remove the call to `myClassList.Add()`.